# Procedural World Generation

Tags: java, random

I am generating my world (random, infinite and 2d) in sections that are x by y, when I reach the end of x a new section is formed. If in section one I have hills, how can I make it so that in section two those hills will continue? Is there some kind of way that I could make this happen?

So it would look something like this

1221

1 = generated land

2 = non generated land that will fill in the two ones

I get this now:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to make this flow better?

Comment: I see your hills continue from top to bottom. What do you mean they are not continuous?

Comment: The flip effect was due to a image mirror in the screenshot function, the issue is that the cliff cuts off sharply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like just an algorithm issue. Your generation mechanism needs a start point. On the initial call it would be say 0, on subsequent calls it would be the finishing position of the previous "chunk".

If I was doing this, I'd probably make the height of the next point plus of minus say 0-3 from the previous, using some sort of distribution - e.g. 10% of the time it's +/1 3, 25% of the time it is +/- 2, 25% of the time it is 0 and 40% of the time it is +/- 1.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, here is a solution:

If you generated the delta (difference) between the hills and capped at a fixed value (so changes are never too big), then you can carry over the value of the last hill from the previous section when generating the new one and apply the first randomly genenarted delta (of the new section) to the carried-over hill size.

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating these "hills" sequentially, I would create an accessor method that provides the continuation of said hill with a value to begin the next section. It seems that you are creating a random height for the hill to be constrained by some value already when drawing a hill in a single section. Extend that functionality with this new accessor method.

My take on a possible implementation of this.

```
public class DrawHillSection {
    private int index;
    private int x[50];
    public void drawHillSection() {
        for( int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                getPreviousHillSectionHeight(index - 1)
            }
            else {
                ...
                // Your current implementation to create random
                //   height with some delta-y limit.
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    public void getPreviousHillSectionHeight(int index)
    {
        return (x[49].height);
    }
}
```